# JDBC connection issue ubuntu and PHP Storm

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, jdbc, phpstorm

Im trying to connect to the database using DB navigator in PHP Storm.

I can already connect to my database which is a VPS on digitalocean with php and PDO using localhost as the host and the username and password setup through PHPmyadmin. I don't understand why that works since my database is stored on Digital Oceans VPS but it works, i can write to and from the database no problem and access my database at www.mywebsite/phpadmin

normally when localhosts works it means i have LAMP installed on my local machine but i don't and when i worked previously with shared hosting for another site the host was the ip address.

Anyway i didn't worry about it since it works for my PHP connection but now im trying to use DB navigator with PHPstorm and it needs to setup the database connection. since im using the same username and password that works for php connection to the database i assume that is correct.

I have installed the driver library and selected the .com.mysql.jdbc.Driver as the driver. 
for URL which i assume must be host i have tried the following:

pretend droplet ip = 123.456.789 
pretend website is: www.mywebsite.com

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 
jdbc:mysql://123.456.789:3306 
jdbc:mysql://mywebsite.com:3306 
jdbc:mysql://www.mywebsite.com:3306
```

None of these work and all say no packets received. I also tried with the data source option in php designer with the same results. Anyone know what the correct connection string is, maybe i have the string structured wrong, im new to ubuntu and these VPS systems, i have ssh access also if that matters?

Comment: Where do you run PhpStorm: on your VPS or locally on your home/work computer? If locally, then you need to make sure that: 1) MySQL port (3306) is opened in your firewall and 2) MySQL is configured to accept external connections (not from local IP). The PhpMyAdmin is running on the VPS already, so it is considered a local connection and above requirements do not really apply in such case.

Comment: yeah PHP storm is running locally, i already have it configured to accept external connections. Ill look at opening 3306, im just running windows firewall.

Assuming i fix that do you know which of the above jdbc connections are correct? Are they structured ok or is there any missing info?

Comment: Opening MySQL port in firewall -- it should be done on remote server not local PC. About connection string: 1st one is wrong since it attempt to connect to the local computer; other 3 are OK (as long as all of them resolve to the same remote IP)